# Should SI register be FFFFh after LODSB when it is 0000h

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

Im making an 8086 emulator, and testing it with IBMPCBIOSv3 of 5150.
But it halts because of SI register is FFFF after LODSB.
SI register is 0 before LODSB, so it should be -1 already after LODSB.
or anything else?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: `0xffff` *is* `-1`, in a 16bit register.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, by the way, i found the issue source. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If the direction flag is clear and SI=0x0000 before the LODSB, then SI will be 0x0001 after the LODSB.

If the direction flag is set and SI=0x0000 before the LODSB, then SI will be 0xFFFF after the LODSB.

Comment: I mean, DF is set.